# Pandas взять значение строки ниже

Tags: python, pandas

Всем привет. Есть такая модель реальных данных:

```
    C  S  E  D 
1   1  3  0  0
2   1  5  0  0
3   1  6  0  0
4   2  1  0  0
5   2  3  0  0
6   2  7  0  0
```

С - category, S - start, E - end, D - delta

**Нужно при помощи pandas в столбец Е занести значение столбца S с условием id = id+1, причем последнее значение Е категории равно значению из столбца S той же строки
Получается:**

```
    C  S  E  D 
1   1  3  5  0
2   1  5  6  0
3   1  6  6  0
4   2  1  3  0
5   2  3  7  0
6   2  7  7  0
```

И затем вычесть S из Е и занести это в D. Это, в принцпе, легко. Сложность именно с заполнением столбца E

В итоге получается это:

```
    C  S  E  D 
1   1  3  5  2
2   1  5  6  1
3   1  6  6  0
4   2  1  3  2
5   2  3  7  4
6   2  7  7  0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df['E'] = df.groupby('C')['S'].shift(-1).fillna(df['S']).astype(int)
df['D'] = df['E'] - df['S']
```

или

```
df = df.assign(E = df.groupby('C')['S'].shift(-1).fillna(df['S']).astype(int),
               D = lambda x: x['E'] - x['S'])
```